# Правильно завершить потоки в форме.

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Всем привет! У меня есть код который загружает и проверяет прокси сервера на доступность. То есть, если ответ от сервера 200, значит работает. Если любой другой не работает, все идет хорошо, но потоки в форме не останавливаются. Помогите решить проблему, как остановить все потоки и выйти из цикла, вот код:

```
#region Settings
public static string _url;
public static string[] _readproxy;
public static IEnumerator _proxylist;
public static Queue<Exception> _exceptions = new Queue<Exception>();
public static Thread[] _thread;
#endregion

#region StartButton
private void StartCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   _url = TargetSave.Text;
   _readproxy = File.ReadAllLines("proxy.txt");
   _proxylist = _readproxy.GetEnumerator();

   _thread = new Thread[_threadcount];

   for (int i = 0; i < _threadcount; i++) // запускаем потоки.
   {
         ManualResetEvent[] _handles = new ManualResetEvent[_threadcount];
         _handles[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);

         _thread[i] = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart((method_head)));
         _thread[i].Start(_handles[i]);
   }

}
#endregion

#region ProxyPrase
public void ProxyPrase(string proxy)
{
     try 
     {
         string _proxyprase = proxy;
         int _pos = _proxyprase.IndexOf(":");

         if (_pos != -1)
         {
            _proxyhost = _proxyprase.Substring(0, _pos);
            _proxyport = _proxyprase.Substring(_pos + 1);
         }
         else
         {
            return;
         }
     }
     catch
     {
        return;
     }

}
#endregion

#region StopButton
private void StopCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try 
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < _threadcount; i++) // остановкэ
  {
     _thread[i].Abort();

  }
   }
   catch
   {
      return;
   }
}
#endregion

public void method_head(object handle)
{
   while (true)
   {
      try
      {
         lock (_proxylist)
         {
            if (_proxylist.MoveNext())
            {
               _proxyline = _proxylist.Current as string;
            }
            else
            {
               break; // если в файле нету больше прокси серверов то выходим из цикла
            }

            ProxyPrase(_proxyline);
      }
      try
      {
         HttpWebRequest headrequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(@"http://" + _url); // сайт для проверки например www.google.ru

         headrequest.Proxy = new WebProxy(_proxyhost, Convert.ToInt32(_proxyport));
         headrequest.Timeout = 5000;
         headrequest.Method = "HEAD";
         headrequest.UserAgent = _requseragent;

         HttpWebResponse headresponse = (HttpWebResponse)headrequest.GetResponse();

         txtWorkingProxies.Text += ("Прокси сервер: (" + _proxyline + ") возвратил ответ: " + headresponse.StatusCode + " (GodProxy) " + Environment.NewLine);

         headresponse.Close();

      }
      catch (WebException ScanExcp)
      {
         txtWorkingProxies.Text += ("Прокси сервер: (" + _proxyline + ") возвратил ответ: " + ((HttpWebResponse)ScanExcp.Response).StatusCode + " (BadProxy) " + Environment.NewLine);

      }
   }
   catch (ThreadAbortException)
   {
      break;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      lock (_exceptions)
      {
         _exceptions.Enqueue(ex);
      }

      continue;
    }

      ((ManualResetEvent)handle).Set();
  }}
```

PS. Знаю, код, наверно, плохой. Но он работает! В консольном режиме очень даже хорошо.

PSS. Пытался останавливать разными способами - форма то зависнет, то не реагирует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте через `Interrupt()` на крайняк, хотя это не очень хорошо будет? Но вообще беда у вас с глобальными статическими переменными! Попробуйте для начала сделать их не статик - у вас явно идёт дедлок где-то. И оберните в тру кетч весь код в треде (до вайл).